# Removing an appended element in an if statement Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

This code should fire a function onKeyUp on an input then check if value of the string is less than 3 characters; if so then it appends a span to a div displaying an error message. Once more than 2 characters have been entered, it should remove the error span. Curretly it does not remove the error span element. It also does not produce any errors in the console for debugging the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
$('#first_name_up').keyup(function(){
    if($('#first_name_up').length < 3){
        $('#first_name_fail').remove();
        $( "<span id='first_name_fail' class='fail'>Enter valid first name</span>" ).appendTo($('#fails'));
    } else {
        $('#fails span').empty();
    }

});
```

Comment: try using keydown event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
$('#first_name_up').length
```

should be

```
$('#first_name_up').val().length
```

or

```
$(this).val().length
```

as you are calculating length of value in the input.

Comment: I hope its working and the length of value is what you had asked for.

Comment: @user3787751 welcome to SO, and if you feel that this answer has fulfilled your need then try to accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark available with this answer after 15 mins.. And by the way, it is not a compulsion... :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, thanks for the comment. The correct way to deal with new users.

Answer (score 0):

There are no console errors, because the error is in the logic. Like @Shaunak_D suggest, you are checking the length of the elements being returned, not the length of the string in the input. Here is an example I tested, which may work your you, if you did not understand the previous answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="first_name_up" name="first_name_up" />
        <div id="fails"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $first_name_up = $('#first_name_up'), // Reduces traversing the DOM.
                $fails = $('#fails'), // Reduces traversing the DOM.
                // Makes the code below a bit easier to read.
                failHtml = '<span id="first_name_fail" class="fail">Enter valid first name</span>';

            $first_name_up.keyup(function () {
                if($first_name_up.val().length < 3){
                    $('#first_name_fail').remove();
                    $( failHtml ).appendTo($fails);
                } else {
                    $fails.find('span').empty();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```